# jQuery datepicker not working with iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, jquery-ui-datepicker

```
 $(function () {
        $('.Month-Picker').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: false,
            dateFormat: 'MM-yy',
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                $("#<%=btnMonthYear.ClientID %>").click();
            },
            beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
                if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                    year = datestr.substring(datestr.length - 4, datestr.length);
                    month = jQuery.inArray(datestr.substring(0, datestr.length - 5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                    $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                }
            }
        });
    });
```

I have a jQuery datepicker through which I choose the "Month-Year" Its working fine with every browser except the iPad. Please have look at the enclosed image.
[image: error with jQuery Datepicker]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var postForm = false;

    $(function () {
        $('.Month-Picker').datepicker({
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: false,
            dateFormat: 'MM-yy',
            onChangeMonthYear: function () { postForm = true; },
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                $("#<%=btnMonthYear.ClientID %>").click();
            },
            beforeShow: function (input, inst) {
                if ((datestr = $(this).val()).length > 0) {
                    year = datestr.substring(datestr.length - 4, datestr.length);
                    month = jQuery.inArray(datestr.substring(0, datestr.length - 5), $(this).datepicker('option', 'monthNames'));
                    $(this).datepicker('option', 'defaultDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                    postForm = false;
                }
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#aspnetForm").click(function () {
            if (postForm == true) {
                postForm = false;
                var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                $("#<%=btnMonthYear.ClientID %>").click();
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use chrome developer tools.(F12)

Settings> Overrides> "User Agent"  select iPad.

Both Chrome and Safari using WebKit. You can Easily emulate iPad and debug.

Comment: Even using this, i could not reproduce an issue, that was on ipad, safari and chome. So the emulation is not 100% correct