# jQuery date picker not working in iPad

Tags: jquery, ipad, datepicker

Following jQuery date picker is working on all the browsers including Safari, but not iPad.

```
<div class="tab3_4_bar1" id="Bar3">
    <div class="Bar_header">Start Date</div>
    <div id="Bar3Content" class="BarContent"></div>
    <input id="StartDate" class="myDate" />
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function() {
    $("#StartDate").datepicker({
        showButtonPanel: true,
        showOn: 'focus',
        buttonImage: "../imgs/img.png",
        buttonImageOnly: true
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#StartDate{  
   width: 70px;  
}
```

Any quick fix?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery datepicker not working with iPad](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404802/jquery-datepicker-not-working-with-ipad)

Comment: It did not help me out!

Answer (score 0):

use input type="text" instead of "date".

```
<div>
    <form action="${app}/fixture" method="get">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" name="matchdate" id="matchdate" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Get Fixtures" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>


<script>
    $(function() {
        $("#matchdate").datetimepicker({
            format : "d-m-Y",
            timepicker : false,
            inline : true
        });
    });
</script>
```